# Strange problem after server migration with MS Edge / Trac

Tags: microsoft-edge, trac, http-authentication

I have just moved our [Trac](https://trac.edgewall.org/) environment from one server to another. They are both running Ubuntu 18.04 with Trac 1.2.5 on Apache.

I use account manager with .htdigest authentification.

With Firefox, Chrome, Internet Explorer and Safari, everything works fine, but when I try to access https://ticket.mydomain.com and enter the username and password in MS Edge, the http authentication window where I enter the password appears over and over again (username&password are correct). When I then enter the URL https://ticket.mydomain.com/wiki in the same session (Edge window), it works and I am immediately logged in.
When I close Edge and open it again with the link https://ticket.mydomain.com/wiki and enter my credentials, everything works fine as well.

Does anyone have an idea what could cause this issue? It's driving me crazy...

Thanks for any hints!

Comment: Perhaps the issue is related to the browser cache or cookie, try to clear the browser cache and cookie, then recheck it. Besides, if still display the same issue, try to use F12 developer tools to check whether there has some error in the Console or Network Tools.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone else sohuld have the same problem: My "solution" was to enable the HTTP authentification in AccountManagerPlugin. It seems like Edge cannot work with the root-directory "/" in the Apache .conf-file...